# Why I am getting the following error opening a xlsx?

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hello I am trying to open a .xlsx file with python, my code is really simple it looks as follows:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('prod334.xlsx')
```

However I am getting an error, I am not sure about the cause of this error since I am just opening the file, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to overcome this failure. 
The error that I am getting is the following:

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vertAlign'
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
main.py in <module>()
      2 
      3 
----> 4 wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('prod334.xlsx')
/usr/local/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.pyc in load_workbook(filename, use_iterators, keep_vba, guess_types, data_only)
    163 
    164     try:
--> 165         _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, use_iterators, keep_vba)
    166     except KeyError:
    167         e = exc_info()[1]
/usr/local/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/excel.pyc in _load_workbook(wb, archive, filename, use_iterators, keep_vba)
    210         assert wb.loaded_theme == None, "even though the theme information is missing there is a theme object ?"
    211 
--> 212     style_properties = read_style_table(archive.read(ARC_STYLE))
    213     style_table = style_properties.pop('table')
    214     wb.shared_styles = style_properties.pop('list')
/usr/local/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.pyc in read_style_table(xml_source)
    221 def read_style_table(xml_source):
    222     p = SharedStylesParser(xml_source)
--> 223     p.parse()
    224     return p.style_prop
/usr/local/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.pyc in parse(self)
     37         self.parse_color_index()
     38         self.style_prop['color_index'] = self.color_index
---> 39         self.font_list = list(self.parse_fonts())
     40         self.fill_list = list(self.parse_fills())
     41         self.border_list = list(self.parse_borders())
/usr/local/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.pyc in parse_fonts(self)
     89         if fonts is not None:
     90             for node in safe_iterator(fonts, '{%s}font' % SHEET_MAIN_NS):
---> 91                 yield self.parse_font(node)
     92 
     93     def parse_font(self, font_node):
/usr/local/lib/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/openpyxl/reader/style.pyc in parse_font(self, font_node)
    105         if color is not None:
    106             font['color'] = Color(**dict(color.items()))
--> 107         return Font(**font)
    108 
    109     def parse_fills(self):
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'vertAlign'
```

Comment: Which version of `openpyxl` are you using? This was a [bug a while back](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/319). Have you tried to run `pip install --upgrade openpyxl`?

Comment: I am not very sure I am doing this using data joy, thanks for the support.

Comment: @CoryKramer Do you know how to print the version?, thanks for the support,

Comment: This does look an older version of openpyxl. You can check the version with `from openpyxl import __version__; print(__version__)` but it looks like there is a problem in the source file. if you can provide the file then please create a bug on the openpyxl bug tracker.

Comment: @CoryKramer I printed the version and I got: 2.0.2, I am not sure if this is related with the issue, thanks a lot for the support.